# question about passing data between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I Have two view Controller`MainViewController` and `DetailViewController`.

I am passing variable from `MainViewController` to `DetailViewController`  like this ->

```
class MainController: UIViewController {
...........
func showMatchDetailsView(matchId: Int) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MatchDetails", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MatchDetailsIdentifier") as! MatchDetailsController
        controller.matchId = matchId // Is it a good practice?
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
}
```

MatchDetailsController

```
class MatchDetailsController: UIViewController {
    //MARK: Class variable
    var matchId: Int?
     .....
    }
```

Comment: also, I am using MVVM Design pattern. is it correct way to get  passed data in ViewController ?

Comment: I don't see any issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this project where a screen (UIViewController) with data list is shown and the detail of the selected item is shown in another screen (UIViewController). I did that example following Clean Architecture with MVVM, Coordinator and a Container DI patterns

Project link in Github: https://github.com/JLPenaLopez/MyFiles

This is an example of the application:

[image: Example App]

You can also follow [this](https://tech.olx.com/clean-architecture-and-mvvm-on-ios-c9d167d9f5b3) post, where Clean Architecture, MVVM and other patterns are very clearly explained, to follow good practices on iOS with Swift